# Perl Regex Grammar For ANTLR Use

Tags: regex, parsing, antlr, grammar

I need to create a regex parser for a project and I am using ANTLR v3 to do this. I am trying to find an up-to-date, Perl6-like regex grammar. Does anyone have a source? Googling for this has been difficult for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By no means a complete coverage of Perl 6 PCRE's grammar, but it's a start: https://github.com/bkiers/PCREParser

#### EDIT

A bit of a late update, I know, but it may be of interest to future visitors of this Q&A.

I've updated the grammar to conform more closely to the [PCRE specs](http://www.pcre.org/pcre.txt). Before delving in the code on Github, you can give the generated parser a test on the page: [pcreparser.appspot.com](http://pcreparser.appspot.com/)

Comment: Perfect! I had found some ANTLR examples, but none of them actually parsed the regex functionally, more of a "char-by-char" parser. Thanks.

Comment: @alphadogg, no problem. Please drop me line either here or by e-mail if (or more probably, *when*) you find an error in the grammar. Thanks!

Comment: @BartKiers Its a nice tool. Another nice to have method is `PCREParser.getGroupCount()` along with existing `PCREParser.getGroup()`